# Customize my dashboard in customer account?

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, wishlist, dashboard

I am customizing my dashboard panel in customer account. There are two things `customer info` and `customer address`.

However when I add the order we can see orders here, but in the dashboard in the `magento_customer  > frontend > dashboard`

There are only two `.phtml` files which we can be customized `info` and `address`.

1. How I can customize the orders. Problem is orders are getting render at top but I want to render them in the last.
2. How I can add the wish list in the my dashboard?

Comment: I think you are using ultimo theme and wishlist already coming in dashboard panel on left on account page

Comment: yeah but i want a small wishlist in the my dashboard also.

Answer (score 0):

Layout file that is responsible for managing the blocks on Customer Account dashboard is `customer_account_index.xml`.

In `Magento_Customer` module, You can found this file here:

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml

In `Magento_Sales` module, You can found this file here:

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Recent" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" after="customer_account_dashboard_hello" template="order/recent.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Above is the block for responsible Recent order list. To change its position, you can change the block name to the new one where you want to show this like after info or after address.

Similar to sales module, you can create new block on Wishlist Module and add that block `Content Container` in `customer_account_index.xml`.

PS: You need to do all this modification in your current theme package.

Comment: for the orders i have found the solution exactly what you are asking but for the wishlist i am having a hard time to finding a wishlist.

Comment: Do you want to show the whole wishlist there as on wish list page ?

Comment: no just images of wishlist products. Small images like. I think i have to made a custom wishlist template?

Comment: Yes you need to add custom template with the same wishlist block and add that block on customer account index page.

Comment: i need to make a new block also ?

Comment: That is completely depend on requirement.  As you can use the same block functions to fetch the wishlist products and perform customization in template

Comment: okay let me see this

Comment: How we can add any static html content in "My Dashboard"? We should not edit files from vendor folder, right?